# UWP - Get Slidervalue from another Page

Tags: xaml, uwp, c++-cx

I've got 2 Pages: My Main-Page and my Settings-Page - both in XAML and xaml.cpp as code behind. I've also got a class where I want to work with the values of the Settings-Class. (As I already asked in another post) I can save the values from the Settings-Page in the cache using the XAML-tag `NavigationCacheMode="Enabled"`. Using this my SliderValue stays the same even when I switch to my Main-Page and back again to Settings-Page.

What I want to do now: Save the value of the slider as soon as it is changed and store this value to a variable to which I have access from a third Class.

What I've got so far (*not working, always showing initialvalue '70'*):

Settings.xaml.cpp:

```
UWPApp::Settings::Settings()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    quality = sldQuality->Value;
}

int Settings::getQuality() {

    return quality;

}

void DirectX12XamlApp::Settings::sldQuality_ValueChanged(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Primitives::RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs^ e)
{
    quality = sldQuality->Value;
}
```

In Settings.xaml.h:

```
public:
        Settings();
        int getQuality();


private:
     int quality;
```

In Settings.xaml:

```
<Slider x:Name="sldQuality" ValueChanged="sldQuality_ValueChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="38,325,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="168" Value="70"/> 
//initial-Value = 70, which is ALWAYS showing when using getQuality() in an other Class
```

In my logicclass I want to use it like this:

```
int quality = Settings::getQuality();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer: save the value of the slider in a public static property, ideally in the separate class.

Recommended answer:
You should use [MVVM](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnshews_blog/2015/09/09/a-minimal-mvvm-uwp-app/) structure in your app, so you would have a separate layer for storing your settings data. You can save the value of the slider in the singleton service, ideally injected through the IoC container. You may also want to save it in the local storage so the settings are saved when the user closes the app.

MVVM is really a standard of XAML-based apps, and the concept is not difficult to learn and implement.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for a way to store and retrieve settings data for your app. Features for that have been built into the UWP. Please refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data) from the Windows Dev Center. Examples on that page are for C#, but all the links to UWP API references contain code snippets for C++ as well.